# CefSharp displaying the bank screen and get refreshed after minimizing and maximizing the window

Tags: c#, window, cefsharp

We are using the Cefharp version (84.4.10) to load the plugin. It's getting used by the customers in production. However, some customers are reporting that they are seeing the blank screen on loading the window.

Below are some of the things tried by the team to narrow down/rule out certain scenarios.

- The issue is not on the plugin side, since able to reproduce the
  issue on the client box even on loading google.com
- Continue to see the issue even after disabling the antivirus on the client machine.
- Seeing the blank screen in case of both WinForm and WPF window.
- Team is unable to reproduce the issue in-house, so it's a machine-specific issue.
- The issue is not due to client code, since we are able to reproduce the issue on the customer machine using the standalone app. This was important to rule out any product code resulting in this behavior. So with this team was able to narrow the issue to Cefsharp.

Steps tried to resolve the issues, as suggested by other users

- Disable GPU acceleration : disable-gpu
- Disable GPU vsync : disable-gpu-vsync

Standalone code using the WPF window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public const double WINDOWWIDTHPER = 27.5;
    public const double WINDOWHEIGHTPER = 80;

    private ChromiumWebBrowser webBrowser;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        double deskHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
        double deskWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

        int windowWidth = Convert.ToInt32(((double)deskWidth) * (WINDOWWIDTHPER / 100.0));
        int windowHeight = Convert.ToInt32(((double)deskHeight) * (WINDOWHEIGHTPER / 100.0));

        this.Width = windowWidth;
        this.Height = windowHeight;

        string path = File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt");
        string LogFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "browser.log");

        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.LogFile = LogFile;
        settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Verbose;
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu"); // Disable GPU acceleration
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync"); //Disable GPU vsync

        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        webBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Address = "https://google.com";
        this.mainGrid.Children.Add(webBrowser);
        this.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Below is error from verbose logs

Error 1

```
  [0722/170611.925:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(1167)] Failed configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
```

Error 2

```
Line 812: Histogram: Net.Certificate.IgnoreCertificateErrorsSPKIListPresent recorded 1 samples, mean = 0.0 (flags = 0x1)
Line 816: Histogram: Net.Certificate.IgnoreErrors recorded 2 samples, mean = 0.0 (flags = 0x1)
Line 1112: Histogram: Net.QuicSession.CloseAllSessionsError recorded 2 samples (flags = 0x1)
Line 1192: Histogram: Net.SSL_Connection_Error recorded 17 samples (flags = 0x1)
Line 1255: Histogram: Net.SpdySession.ClosedOnError recorded 11 samples (flags = 0x1)
Line 2176: Histogram: DirectWrite.Fonts.Proxy.MessageFilterError recorded 14 samples, mean = 1.0 (flags = 0x1)
Line 2181: Histogram: DiskCache.4.Error recorded 2 samples, mean = 7.5 (flags = 0x1)
Line 2915: Histogram: UMA.PersistentAllocator.FieldTrialAllocator.Errors recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1)
```

Please find the attached [Bankscreen screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At7zn.png) from the customer box.  Any help on this is much appreciated!!!

Comment: If your customer has an Intel 11th Gen iris graphics cards then you'll need upgrade the drivers or disable WPF hardware acceleration. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058136/graphics/graphics-for-11th-generation-intel-processors.html